# Update only one record in SQL Server conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have the following result stored in a temp table `#tempResult`

```
SourceGuid           SourceTypeID         IsSelected
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
84588BAF068320450908      129                  0
5367D0F80A0F4040E909      658                  0    <
872791440CDBE04F7C0B      658                  0    <
15ABA6B70E4A70463E0B      887                  0
1DE39F9805A8A044B20B      887                  0
3F96C93501144041D50A      887                  0
6A01DFF705861049F509      887                  0
```

I need to make IsSelected value to 1 of **only one and not both** of the record marked with `<` to 1 regardless of any other condition just SourceTypeID = 658

How can I achieve this, thanks.

Comment: So you just need one row to be updated, but not all, based on the `WHERE` condition?

Comment: Update tbl_name set column=yourvalue WHERE condition = true

Comment: @FelixPamittan yes and only one record where sourceid = 658 not all

Comment: @Mono your suggestion will update both the records right?

Comment: Yes it will, ok now I saw your edit. Wasn't clear before. But how you want to determine which one should be updated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CTE` to get the `TOP 1` and then do the `UDPATE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM #tempResult
    WHERE SourceTypeId = 658
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)
UPDATE CTE SET IsSelected = 1
```

`ORDER BY NEWID()` denotes random sort. Replace `NEWID()` with the column you want the `TOP` to be based on.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this? @Felix

Comment: i am getting error while executing the statement, in order by and also with WITH

Comment: @RandomUser, if you want to filter on multiple `SourceTypeId`, @sagi's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tempResult 
    SET IsSelected = 1 
WHERE SourceGuid IN (
    SELECT SourceGuid 
    FROM tempResult 
    WHERE SourceTypeId = 658 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: This works only in MySQL. In SQL Server you need Top 1.

Comment: Yes, for SQL aggregate function top has to be used (since limit is not supported)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `CTE` :

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.SourceTypeID ORDER BY t.sourceGuid) as rnk
   FROM YourTable t)
UPDATE CTE
set IsSelected = 1
WHERE rnk = 1
```

This will be dynamic and will work for the entire data, if you just want `SourceTypeID = 658` to be updated, then add a `WHERE` clause :

```
WHERE SourceTypeId = 658
```

Inside the `CTE`

Comment: Thanks for the solution